# Soundness of temporal modal logic rule

Tags: logic, computer-science, modal-logic, sequent-calculus

I am trying to prove the soundness of a temporal modal logic with this rule:

$$
\dfrac{\Sigma \vdash \Theta}{\bigcirc \Sigma \vdash \bigcirc \Theta}
$$

The semantics given a $\omega$-word $u : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow 2^{\mathcal{P}}$ and an enviroment $\rho : \mathcal{V} \rightarrow 2^{\mathcal{N}}$ are:

$$
\parallel \bigcirc \varphi \parallel_{\rho}^u = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \;|\; n+1 \in \parallel \varphi \parallel_{\rho}^u \} 
$$

I believe the correct notion of soundness should be:

Assuming $\forall u. [(\forall \rho \; i. i \in \parallel \Sigma \parallel_{\rho}^u) \implies (\forall \rho \; i. i \in \parallel \Theta \parallel_{\rho}^u)]$ then $\forall u. [(\forall \rho \; i. i \in \parallel \bigcirc \Sigma \parallel_{\rho}^u) \implies (\forall \rho \; i. i \in \parallel \bigcirc \Theta \parallel_{\rho}^u)]$

Is this the correct notion of soundness?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact semantics you're using, but at a glance that looks correct to me

Comment: Apart from your atrocious notation, this looks correct.